# Site with 3 different forms and responses change?

Tags: php, html, forms, html-email

So I am working on a site that has 3 forms on it.

Right now, all 3 forms send the same generic response to an admin of the site and the user who filled out the form using a script called "`NMS FormMail Version 3.14c1`". This script seems limited in only being able to send a single response to form(s).

What I need to do is this: The pages are `html/php` and I need to be able to send a specific email to both the user (based on an email entry) and an admin with other data captured out of the input fields on the form. Each form will have a specific different corresponding email.

Currently, this particular script just pulls the values from the name tag within html input and all. My searches haven't revealed a quick and straight forward way of doing this. Am hoping that some of you have some ideas here?

Comment: did you try anything yet? or just searched Google?

Answer (score 0):

Well you do it as follows. First the HTML part. Create a form in which you have your 3 categories against which you want to send three different responses.

```
<form method=post action=redirectpage.php>
<select name=category><option value=res1>Response 1</option><option value=res2>Response 2</option><option value=res3>Response 3></option></select>
<input type=text name=fullname>
<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>
</form>
```

So when this form is submitted the page is redirected to redirectpage.php. On this page we will do all the tricks. Firstly we will get the values of fields filled. In our case it will be as follows

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
```

If you aren't sure what $_POST does feel free to read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Once you have the variables you can have different responses for different categories.

```
$mailmessage['res1'] = "hello this is response 1";
$mailmessage['res2'] = "hello this is response 2";
$mailmessage['res3'] = "hello this is response 3";
```

Now we will use mail function to send email. Read more about mail function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

```
$msg = $mailmessage[$category];
mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
```

The first line in last code will select message based on the category selected in the form. And then email it to someone@example.com with subject 'My subject' and message selected in line 1.

I hope this helps your purpose and also helps you better understand how to use some basic functions of php. If you need any further assistance please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong this this:

```
<p><?php echo $_REQUEST["first_name"]; ?></p>
```

Which is overall part of this:

```
<?php
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $to = "example@gmail.com, example@gmail.com";
    $subject = "HTML email for ALPS";

    $message = "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>English in the USA Contact</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p><?php echo $_REQUEST["first_name"]; ?></p>
            <p>Thank you for the following inquiry:</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

That is causing this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /usr/home/web/users/a0008565/html/mail-contactus.php on line 13
```

Comment: The $message part has <?php tag starting within php code. You have not closed the previous instance and opened a new one

Comment: Mark you need to stop posting answers like this and focus on one code. its impossible to help you like this

Comment: Thanks - I always get that mixed up. So then do you not add the html inside of the message tag?

Comment: Yes you do. Here is a small tutorial to help you http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Also, adding this as the page which collects the form data then post to the other page which should send an email as noted above. This form page (php) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<title>ALPS Language School</title>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sidemenu ul > li:last-child").css("borderBottom", "none");
}); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-26679474-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="innerwrap" class="clearfix">
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<div id="maincontent" class="clearfix">
<div id="contentleft">
<?php include("contact-side-menu.php"); ?>
</div>
<div id="contentmiddle" class="contact">
<h1>contact us</h1>
<h2 class="clearright largegapbottom">Students</h2>
<div id="contactleft">
<h3 class="largegapbottom">Questions? Comments? Concerns? Feel free to contact us at:</h3>
<p class="address">Contact: <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!--
var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",ol=x.length,l=ol;while(x.charCodeAt(l/13)!" +
"=101){try{x+=x;l+=l;}catch(e){}}for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){o+=x.charAt(i);}return " +
"o.substr(0,ol);}f(\")25,\\\"%-'28'y8*x{p<PCZkeXeCa{njbjFBnf020\\\\4BY&[$J32" +
"0\\\\130\\\\000\\\\230\\\\600\\\\QR3300\\\\200\\\\710\\\\E+:=200\\\\610\\\\" +
"1n\\\\*n\\\\220\\\\t\\\\393130\\\\330\\\\5?6630\\\\l: ?;0=m220\\\\p*.8!h&zg" +
"l-.$4VLJ220\\\\OT\\\\\\\\UBUZP\\\"(f};o nruter};))++y(^)i(tAedoCrahc.x(edoC" +
"rahCmorf.gnirtS=+o;721=%y{)++i;l<i;0=i(rof;htgnel.x=l,\\\"\\\"=o,i rav{)y,x" +
"(f noitcnuf\")"                                                              ;
while(x=eval(x));
//-->
//]]>
</script>
</p>
<p class="address">Phone 206.720.6363</p>
<p>Fax 206.720.1806</p>
<hr/>
<h3 class="largegaptop">Or fill out the form below and we will get back to you soon.</h3>
</div>
<div id="contactright">
<iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Alps+Language+School&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=39.729049,106.962891&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Alps+Language+School&amp;hnear=&amp;cid=6369747657762772736&amp;ll=47.655444,-122.310104&amp;spn=0.08094,0.102654&amp;z=12&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Alps+Language+School&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=39.729049,106.962891&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Alps+Language+School&amp;hnear=&amp;cid=6369747657762772736&amp;ll=47.655444,-122.310104&amp;spn=0.08094,0.102654&amp;z=12&amp;iwloc=A">View Larger Map</a></small></div>
<form  action="http://www.englishintheusa.com/mail-contactus.php" method="post" id="contactform">
    <input type="hidden" value="info" name="recipient"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="print_blank_fields"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="http://www.englishintheusa.com/students_conf.php" name="redirect"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="Contact Form" name="subject"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="first_name,last_name,email" name="required"/>
    <p><label for="first_name">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="first_name" id="first_name"/></p>
    <p><label for="last_name"> Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="last_name" id="last_name"/></p>
    <p><label for="address_street">Street:</label>
     <input type="text" size="30" name="address_street" id="address_street"/></p>
    <p><label for="address_city">City:</label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="address_city" id="address_city"/></p>
    <p><label for="address_state">State/Province:</label>
     <input type="text" size="30" name="address_state" id="address_state"/></p>
    <p><label for="address_country">Country:</label>
<select name="address_country" id="address_country">
<option value="">Country...</option>
<option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
<option value="Antigua &amp; Barbuda">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
<option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Austria">Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize">Belize</option>
<option value="Benin">Benin</option>
<option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
<option value="Bonaire">Bonaire</option>
<option value="Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
<option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="British Indian Ocean Ter">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
<option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
<option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
<option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Canary Islands">Canary Islands</option>
<option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="Chad">Chad</option>
<option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
<option value="Chile">Chile</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
<option value="Cocos Island">Cocos Island</option>
<option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
<option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
<option value="Congo">Congo</option>
<option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="Cote DIvoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
<option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
<option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
<option value="Curaco">Curacao</option>
<option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
<option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
<option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
<option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
<option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
<option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
<option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
<option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
<option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
<option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
<option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
<option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
<option value="Finland">Finland</option>
<option value="France">France</option>
<option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
<option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="French Southern Ter">French Southern Ter</option>
<option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
<option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
<option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="Great Britain">Great Britain</option>
<option value="Greece">Greece</option>
<option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
<option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
<option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="Guam">Guam</option>
<option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
<option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
<option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
<option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
<option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
<option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
<option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
<option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
<option value="Iran">Iran</option>
<option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
<option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
<option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
<option value="Israel">Israel</option>
<option value="Italy">Italy</option>
<option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>
<option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
<option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
<option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
<option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
<option value="Korea Sout">Korea South</option>
<option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
<option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="Laos">Laos</option>
<option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
<option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
<option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
<option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
<option value="Libya">Libya</option>
<option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
<option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Macau">Macau</option>
<option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
<option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
<option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
<option value="Mali">Mali</option>
<option value="Malta">Malta</option>
<option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
<option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
<option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
<option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
<option value="Midway Islands">Midway Islands</option>
<option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
<option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
<option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
<option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
<option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
<option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
<option value="Nambia">Nambia</option>
<option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
<option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
<option value="Netherland Antilles">Netherland Antilles</option>
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
<option value="Nevis">Nevis</option>
<option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
<option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="Niger">Niger</option>
<option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
<option value="Niue">Niue</option>
<option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="Norway">Norway</option>
<option value="Oman">Oman</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Palau Island">Palau Island</option>
<option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
<option value="Panama">Panama</option>
<option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
<option value="Peru">Peru</option>
<option value="Phillipines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Pitcairn Island">Pitcairn Island</option>
<option value="Poland">Poland</option>
<option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
<option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
<option value="Republic of Montenegro">Republic of Montenegro</option>
<option value="Republic of Serbia">Republic of Serbia</option>
<option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
<option value="Romania">Romania</option>
<option value="Russia">Russia</option>
<option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
<option value="St Barthelemy">St Barthelemy</option>
<option value="St Eustatius">St Eustatius</option>
<option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
<option value="St Kitts-Nevis">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
<option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
<option value="St Maarten">St Maarten</option>
<option value="St Pierre &amp; Miquelon">St Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
<option value="St Vincent &amp; Grenadines">St Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
<option value="Saipan">Saipan</option>
<option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
<option value="Samoa American">Samoa American</option>
<option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
<option value="Sao Tome &amp; Principe">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
<option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
<option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
<option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
<option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
<option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
<option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
<option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
<option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
<option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
<option value="Syria">Syria</option>
<option value="Tahiti">Tahiti</option>
<option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
<option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
<option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
<option value="Togo">Togo</option>
<option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
<option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
<option value="Trinidad &amp; Tobago">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
<option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
<option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="Turks &amp; Caicos Is">Turks &amp; Caicos Is</option>
<option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
<option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Erimates">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
<option value="Uraguay">Uruguay</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State</option>
<option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
<option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
<option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
<option value="Wallis &amp; Futana Is">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
<option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
<option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="address_zip">Zip:</label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="address_zip" id="address_zip"/></p>
<p><label for="email">Your  e-mail: </label>
 <input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email"/></p>
<p><label for="phone">Your phone number: </label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="phone" id="phone"/></p>
<p><label for="instructions">Comments:</label>
  <textarea   cols="25" rows="3" name="instructions" id="instructions"></textarea></p>
<p class="submit">  <input type="submit" value="Contact ALPS" name="Submit"/></p>

          </form>

</div>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```